# yaml cpp error: 'YAML::TypedBadConversion<std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> > >'

Tags: c++, cmake, yaml, yaml-cpp

I want to read a vector from a yaml file but when I try to do this I am getting the following error

> terminate called after throwing an instance of 'YAML::TypedBadConversion<std::vector<double, std::allocator > >'
> what():  bad conversion
> Aborted (core dumped)

My main program is

```
bool fileLoaded = false;
YAML::Node config;

std::vector<double> target_jpos;

try
{
    config = YAML::LoadFile("/config/test.yaml");
    fileLoaded = true;
}
catch(std::exception& e)
{
    fileLoaded = false;
}

target_jpos = config["target_jpos"].as<std::vector<double> >();

if(fileLoaded)
    std::cout << "File loaded successfully \n\t target_jpos[0]: " << target_jpos[0] << "\n";
else
    std::cout << "File failed to load\n";
```

and my test.yaml file is

```
target_jpos: [-0.6, -1.0, 2.7, 0.6, -1.0, 2.7, -0.6, -1.0, 2.7, 0.6, -1.0, 2.7]
```

everything looks alright but don't know why I am getting this error. Does someone have any idea on solving this?

EDIT:
my CMakeLists.txt is

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)
add_subdirectory(yaml-cpp)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-std=c++11")

add_executable(yaml-parser main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(yaml-parser yaml-cpp)
```

My tree structure is

```
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── config
│   └── test.yaml
├── main.cpp
└── yaml-cpp
```

EDIT: Here's the [link](https://github.com/HariP19/Yaml-Parser.git) to the full program.

Comment: Please extract and provide a [mcve], which includes not just code but input data as well. From your code, it's particularly unclear what state `fileLoaded` has. BTW: Why do you catch and ignore an exception only to set a flag and later evaluate that flag? You're making very bad use of exceptions as flow control utility here, but that's probably not causing your problems.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt I have added the link to the basic program. Could you please check it once

Comment: No, sorry, that doesn't work like that. You have to extract a [mcve] (not your whole project) and include that inline in the question.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt I have edited my question. Please kindly check if it's ok. Everything looks ok to me but I could not find what's the error here, that's why added the program. One thing I am not sure is if I have given the correct filepath. Would be great if you could help.

Answer (score 0):

The error says that you're trying to access the wrong type. In my usage of yaml-cpp I have only used `float`s, and they have worked perfectly. Maybe the library doesn't support `double`s?

Try:

```
std::vector<float> target_jpos;
target_jpos = config["target_jpos"].as<std::vector<float>>();
```

Comment: Does your YAML file start with `---`? @HariP19

Comment: No it doesn't. I have added the github link to the program. Would be great if you could check it @SparkyPotato

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are trying to pull data from the `YAML::Node` before you have checked if the file has successfully loaded. The load is throwing an exception, so your check is reached. Always check for success *before* using the data.

On another note, you can fix your YAML file by changing it to:

```
---
target_jpos: [-0.6, -1.0, 2.7, 0.6, -1.0, 2.7, -0.6, -1.0, 2.7, 0.6, -1.0, 2.7]
```

Comment: As far as I can see, I am extracting the data on line `target_jpos = config["target_jpos"].as<std::vector<float> >();` which comes after loading the file at `config = YAML::LoadFile("./config/test.yaml");`

Comment: @HariP19 What if the load fails?

Comment: Shouldn't I be getting `YAML::BadFile` error instead if that's the case

Comment: That exception is being caught when you're loading, and you're setting `fileLoaded` to false in the catch block.

Comment: Ok I got it. I removed the catch exception block and now getting the BadFile error. Any idea why the file can't be read? I have tried adding "---" to the yaml file

Comment: The file path is probably wrong in relation to the working directory.

Comment: Yes! This was the case indeed. I forgot to give the path with respect to the build directory. `../config/test.yaml` added two dots to the filepath and it's working now. Thank you very much for you help.